# C variable type assert

Tags: c

```
uint32_t fail_count = 0;

...

if(is_failed)
    if(fail_count < UINT32_MAX - 1 )
        ++fail_count;
```

It works fine, but this code is fragile. Tomorrow, I may change the type of `fail_count` from `uint32_t` to `int32_t` and I forget to update `UINT32_MAX`.

Is there any way to assert `fail_count` is a `uint32_t` at the function where I have written my `if`s?

**P.S. 1-** I know it is easy in C++ but I'm looking for a C way.

**P.S. 2-** I prefer to use two asserts than relying on the compiler warnings. Checking the number size via `sizeof` should work but is there any way to distinguish if type is unsigned?

Comment: I don't think so. C doesn't have any type introspection mechanisms.

Comment: You could use macros to define your types, and the macro could create two variables.

Comment: A decent compiler will warn of the comparison `fail_count < UINT32_MAX - 1` if `fail_count` is `int32_t` as the comparison will always be true. (as well as a comparison between *signed* and *unsigned* types)

Comment: you want it for any specific compiler or in general?

Comment: @P.W a specific embedded device compiler. But I look for a robust code that works on both `IAR` and `GCC`.

Comment: Even with `uint16_t` you should still get `"warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, true but not bullet proof against `uint64_t`. I have no problem to use two asserts but I prefer not to rely on warnings. I am wondering if there is an assert against negative values.

Comment: That is the sticky-wicket. There is no direct run-time test for type. There are macros that can test type-equality or whether types are "compatible", e.g. `__typeof__(x)`, but that isn't a direct test of an individual type.

Comment: You can have `assert(fail_count != -1);`

Comment: @Achal, then I will see a lot of warnings at each compilation.

Comment: In your code snippet could assert that failcount does not wrap (which is the condition you are really after in there): `old_failcount=failcount++; assert(old_failcount<failcount)`

Comment: What are you doing where the possibility of UNIT32_MAX failures exists?  That would take a loooong time - like even with 1000 failures per second, you're looking at almost 2 months of run time to hit that limit...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As of C11, you can use a [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) macro to produce a result based on the type of an expression. You can use the result in a [static assertion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert):

```
#define IS_UINT32(N) _Generic((N), \
  uint32_t: 1, \
  default: 0 \
)

int main(void) {
  uint32_t fail_count = 0;
  _Static_assert(IS_UINT32(fail_count), "wrong type for fail_count");
}
```

You could of course use the result in a regular `assert()`, but `_Static_assert` will fail at compile time.

A better approach could be dispatching the comparison based on type, again using generic selection:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define UNDER_LIMIT(N) ((N) < _Generic((N), \
int32_t: INT32_MAX, \
uint32_t: UINT32_MAX \
) -1)

int main(void) {
  int32_t fail_count = 0;

  if (UNDER_LIMIT(fail_count)) {
    ++fail_count;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned GCC, you can use a compiler extension to accomplish this in case you are not using C11:

First write a macro that emulates the C++ `is_same`. And then call it with the types you want to compare.

A minimal example for your particular case:

```
#include<assert.h>

#define is_same(a, b) \
  static_assert(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b)), #a " is not unsigned int")

int main()
{
    int fail_count = 0;    
    is_same(fail_count, unsigned int);
}
```

The compiler asserts:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:4:3: error: static assertion failed: "fail_count is not unsigned int"
   static_assert(__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b)), #a " is not unsigned int")
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

<source>:9:5: note: in expansion of macro 'is_same'
     is_same(fail_count, unsigned int);
 ^~~~~~~
```

See [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hY_8p4)

Comment: Weird. OP even explicitly answer your question about compilers with "a specific embedded device compiler", _not_ gcc. OP even mentions it should work on IAR too. Still you give a gcc-only answer.

Comment: Actually when I wrote the comment, I was about to write the same answer as Ryan but he wrote it a few minutes before me. So there was no point writing the same again. Also remember that the answers on this site are not just for the OP. What if someone who is still using C99 want to accomplish this task with GCC? So nothing *weird* about this.

Answer (score 1):

What about a low-tech solution that works even with K&R C and any compiler past and present?

Place the right comment in the right place:

```
/*
 * If this type is changed, don't forget to change the macro in
 * if (fail_count < UINT32_MAX - 1) below (or file foobar.c)
 */
uint32_t fail_count = 0;
```

With a proper encapsulation this should refer to exactly one place in the code.
Don't tell me you increment the fail count in many places. And if you do, what
about a

```
#define FAIL_COUNT_MAX  UINT32_MAX
```

right next to the declaration? That's more proper and clean code anyway.
No need for all the assertion magic and rocket sciencery :-)